# Python error while executing plugin GFA in QGIS 2.14.22

Tags: qgis, python

While processing with plugin GFA still loading 3% and error. anyone have solution for this issue?

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

KeyError: 7.0 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/asus/.qgis2/python/plugins\GeomorphicFloodIndex\doGeomorphicFloodIndex.py", line 732, in accept
    x=x+di[fd]
KeyError: 7.0


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.14.22-Essen Essen, 6af20113ec 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/asus/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/asus/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.14/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/asus/.qgis2//python
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\fTools\tools
```

Comment: But why QGIS 2?

Comment: because plugin GFA didn't work in QGIS 3